# Azure database name length

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I don't know if I am being stupid or what, but I just can't find any info on database name restrictions in MS Azure SQL. I mostly find answers about SQL Server, or database size, not the name size...

Is there a limit on Azure SQL database name length, and if there is, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) the **maximum length of identifiers** (this includes database names) is **128 characters**.

Has been the same since SQL Server 2005 (at least). SQL Azure is basically another SQL Server, therefore it probably won't be any different.

Comment: Now I feel like even more of an idiot, since I remembered that I could just try to create a db with a long name and see what error I get.
Anyway, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

from the [Create SQL Database portal interaction](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.SQLDatabase)